# youtube-iframe-api closed captioning troubles

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

Spent a better part of yesterday 6/12/2017 trying figure out why my captioning was not working when I was using the YouTube iframe embed code (generated from the Share > Embed button).

After much experimentation, I narrowed the problem down to what has already been identified. Closed captioning was not working as the captioning was automatically generated.  Once I manually created the closed captioning, everything seemed to work fine.  I didn't even have to use the cc_load_policy=1 parameter.

BUT... Today 6/13/2017, I happened to be working with the same video files and all of a sudden I got different behavior.  When I play the video from a regular YouTube page, I see the captioning.  When I play the video from the iframe embedded players I do not.  Tried all sorts of goofy things to get things to work based on reading.

- recreated the english closed caption (manually created a blurb at beginning).
- set the cc_load_policy=1 parameter
- set yt:cc=on as a tag
- some other goofy things that are not worth mentioning.

CAPTIONING

note: In both cases the domain was: http://www.youtube.com I could only include 2 links in post.

/watch?v=EExO_6PVIXk

NO CAPTIONING:

/embed/EExO_6PVIXk
/embed/EExO_6PVIXk?cc_load_policy=1

I am at a loss. Any direction would be appreciated.

John

Comment: The non functioning links should have been:

1) /embed/EExO_6PVIXk
2) /embed/EExO_6PVIXk?cc_load_policy=1

Comment: Someone also pointed out code got changed YESTERDAY on the IFrame Player API.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Revision_History

Comment: Same problem, with this new revision, the CC menu does not show up. 
Check this video as an embedded and regular url:
https://www.youtube.com/embed/eIho2S0ZahI, 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIho2S0ZahI

Answer (score 0):

Heard through the grapevine that something changed with the YouTube iFrame API yesterday (6/14/17) where CC started to work.

With some testing, I got mixed results (but am working):

1) As of now (6/15/17), the embed video links now show the CC button and will show CC if you had previously enabled closed captioning (kept track in local storage under "yt-html5-player-modules::subtitlesModuleData::module-enabled".

2) If you provide documented the "cc_load_policy=1" parameter to the URL (of the iFrame embed) closed captioning will show regardless of the value in local storage.

3) What didn't work is me loading the iframe as follows:

```
    <iframe
      id="futusign_youtube"
      style="visibility: hidden;"
      frameborder="0"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XIMLoLxmTDw?enablejsapi=1"
    ></iframe>
```

and then trying to set the CC policy in playerVars:

```
    var player = new window.YT.Player('futusign_youtube', {
      playerVars: {
        'controls': 0,
        'enablejsapi': 1,
        'showinfo': 0,
        'rel': 0,
        'cc_load_policy': 1,
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
        'onError': onPlayerError,
      }
    });
```

4) The work-around is to set the cc_load_policy=1 on the URL of the src to the iFrame.

```
    <iframe
      id="futusign_youtube"
      style="visibility: hidden;"
      frameborder="0"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XIMLoLxmTDw?enablejsapi=1&cc_load_policy=1"
    ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a duplicate of this problem:

[Embed Youtube with Captions on by default not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41239654/embed-youtube-with-captions-on-by-default-not-working)

...where adding the `cc_lang_pref=en` option (if you want English) solves the problem.